# Can we do addition of two or more objects of same type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object-type

I have 3 objects of the same type with different values of their property. I would like to add them together as follow :

For example

```
objA = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 0, propertyB: 3, propertyC: 0},
        ....
    }
}
objB = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 0, propertyB: 0, propertyC: 1},
        ....
    }
}
objC = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 4, propertyB: 0, propertyC: 0},
        ....
    }
}
```

And what I want a result like

```
objC = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 4, propertyB: 3, propertyC: 1},
        ...
    } 
}
```

is it possible to add them?

And if not, do you suggest any efficient way of coding for this instead of having three different types for each of them?

**EDIT**: By addition, I mean numerical addition of property values from the three objects. Though the objects also have some properties which could be string, I am only interested in number values.

Comment: you'd need to process the objects ... if they are all guaranteed to have the same key structure, then it should be simple ... but since your objects have `....` in the code you posted, it's clear that there's more to them, so, it'll be a stretch - you also would need to show valid objects, which these are not

Comment: You did not describe what "add them" would even mean.

Comment: loop over the keys and add them up

Comment: @Pointy, seems like they did to me.

Comment: @Bravo, the ... here only signifies more properties but all of the objects are of same type and hence same properties

Comment: so sum all property and sub property ? are they all summable ?

Comment: @Crocsx , some of them are also string, but I am only interested in properties that are number

Comment: You first need to define what "add" means, i.e. an algorithm to add the properties. Then it's about implementation.

Comment: @Meenakshi - I know what it signifies, but if you think it's unimportant to the answer, then so do I

Comment: @epascarello yea but what about the `...` part? What if an object is missing a property; is that 0 or an error?

Comment: also, are all the "summable" properties at the same depth below `data` property- i.e. all at `objX.data.something.property` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it is a lot of looping. How you do the looping can be done a bunch of ways. Easiest way os to look over the objects themselves and add things when they do not exist.

```js
objA = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 0, propertyB: 3, propertyC: 0, x: 'funky-chicken'},
        OP: { OO: 1, ZZ: 2 },
    }
}
objB = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 0, propertyB: 0, propertyC: 1, x: 'funky-chicken'},
        OP: { OO: 1, YY: 100 },
    }
}
objC = { 
    data: {
        SH: { propertyA: 4, propertyB: 0, propertyC: 0},
        AA: { A: 1 },
    }
}

const result = [objA, objB, objC].reduce(({ data }, obj) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj.data);
  entries.forEach(([key, items]) => {
    if (!data[key]){
      data[key] = { ...items };
    } else {
      Object.entries(items).forEach(([item, value]) => {
        if(typeof value === 'number') {
          data[key][item] = ( data[key][item] || 0 ) + value;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return { data };
}, { data: {} })
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, here's one that sums any numbers at any level

The non-number values will have the value of the last object processed (this can be changed if required)

This doesn't handle array properties properly

```js
const objA = {
    data: {
        num: 1,
        SH: {
            propertyA: 0,
            propertyB: 3,
            propertyC: 0
        },
        text: 'objA',
        x: {
          y: {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3
          }
        }
    }
};
const objB = {
    data: {
        num: 2,
        SH: {
            propertyA: 0,
            propertyB: 0,
            propertyC: 1
        },
        text: 'objB',
        x: {
          y: {
            b: 4
          }
        }
    }
};
const objC = {
    data: {
        SH: {
            propertyA: 4,
            propertyB: 0,
            propertyC: 0
        },
        text: 'hello world',
        x: {
          y: {
            a: 1
          }
        }
    }
};

const addObjects = (...objs) => objs.reduce((result, obj) => {
        const fn = (obj, dest = result) => {
            Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                if (typeof value === 'object') {
                    dest[key] = dest[key] || {};
                    fn(value, dest[key]);
                } else {
                    if (typeof value === 'number') {
                        dest[key] = (dest[key] || 0) + value;
                    } else {
                        dest[key] = value;
                    }
                }
            });
            return result;
        };
        return fn(obj, result);
    }, {}
);
console.log(addObjects(objA, objB, objC));
```

Comment: It's not really "easy" is it? :)

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a better way :p that just popped in my head

Comment: Thanks @Bravo , Though it can be considered as a solution but I guess this would not an efficient solution for me since, it's have 15 more properties of type  `SH: {p 
 propertyA: 4,  propertyB: 0,  propertyC: 0  }`.